# How to Solve $ \int _{0}^{\infty} xJ_0(x)\exp(-q^2x^2-bx)\mathrm dx$ integral?

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, bessel-functions

I want to solve the following integral

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty} xJ_0(x)\exp(-q^2x^2-bx) \,\mathrm dx .$$

Firstly I used the expansion of Bessel function $J_0(ax)$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(x)^{2n}}{(n!)^24^n} $$

and expansion of the exponential term

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-b)^k(x)^k}{k!} .$$

The final answer is

$$ =\frac{1}{p^2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2 4^np^{2n}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-b)^k(n+\frac{k}{2})!}{k!p^k}.$$

Also, I tried to simplify the above answer to convert it to the $ \exp(-x^2)$ form, but I could not. Is there any alternative suggestion to solve the integral or convert the form? I need help, please.

Comment: How does one "solve" an integral?

Comment: The best I can get is $I = \sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-b)^k 2^{-1-k} q^{-2-k} {}_1 F_1 \left(1+\frac{k}{2};1;-\frac{1}{4q^2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1+k}{2}\right)}$ which can be expressed in terms of Laguerre polynomials as $I=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-b)^k 2^{-1-k} q^{-2-k} e^{-\frac{1}{4q^2}} L_{\frac{k}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{4q^2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1+k}{2}\right)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could find is [DLMF 10.22.51](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#iv) which is the general integral

$$\int_0^\infty t^{\nu+1}\exp(-p^2t^2) J_\nu(at)\mathrm dt=\frac{a^\nu}{(2p^2)^{\nu+1}}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4p^2}\right)$$
So at least in the case $b=0$ your integral is
$$\frac{1}{2q^2}\exp\left(\frac{-1}{4q^2}\right)$$
I don't know if there are any known expressions for $b\neq 0$ though.

Comment: Dear K.defaoite, thanks a lot. I solved the integral when b=0.